# Remove element from the end and add to the beginning

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I tried this function :

```
var myArray=new Array("1", "2", "3", "4");
var value=myArray.pop();
myArray.push(value);
```

but I'd like to remove 4 from the end and add it to the beginning.
So should be 4 1 2 3. So a LIFO methodology using push and pop... How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var myArray=new Array("1", "2", "3", "4");
var value=myArray.pop();
myArray.splice(0, 0, value);
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `unshift` method ([reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift))

```
var myArray=new Array("1", "2", "3", "4");
var value=myArray.pop();
myArray.unshift(value);
```

Answer (score 3):

You almost had it...

This is how you do it:

```
var myArray=new Array("1", "2", "3", "4");
var value=myArray.pop();
myArray.unshift(value);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var myArray=new Array("1", "2", "3", "4");
myArray.unshift(myArray.pop());
```